# python scraping extracting href from the table

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm trying extract href links from the table. After running the code I receive only links from the first row in the table. Why only first row is checked? What I'm doing wrong?
code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import requests
import select
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://licytacje.komornik.pl/Notice/Search')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Type']/option[text()='Nieruchomość']").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name('button_next_active').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'wMax'}):
    for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
        for a in tr.findAll('a'):
            print(a['href'])
```

the output is:

```
/Notice/Search?sortOrder=DataLicytacji
/Notice/Search?sortOrder=Kategoria
/Notice/Search?sortOrder=Nazwa
/Notice/Search?sortOrder=Miasto
/Notice/Search?sortOrder=Wojew%C3%B3dztwo
/Notice/Search?sortOrder=Cena
```

That are links only from the title row of the table. What with the others?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. I run your exact code and get lots of links printed, like `/Notice/Details/999999` in addition to the ones you added to the question.

Comment: You're right. I don't get it what has changed. Now everything seems ok.